# Is there a possible way for me to load an image and put it on the background of the window in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-itertools

So this is my code, and I have the same code from my last question. I want to upload an image on the window. Right now, it just shows a basic sky and a basic sun, and basic grass. I tried to find a module to help me. I found Pillow, but I don't know how to use it. Can you help? Or the module I want to use can't work with this window or pillow isn't for this.

```
#import modules
from itertools import cycle
from random import randrange 
from tkinter import Canvas, Tk, messagebox, font
#assigning the window variables
canvas_width = 800
canvas_height = 400
#drawing the sky, sun, and grass and making the window
root = Tk ()
c = Canvas(root, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, background='deep sky blue')
c.create_rectangle(-5, canvas_height - 100,  canvas_width + 5, canvas_height + 5, \
                   fill='sea green' , width=0)
c.create_oval(-80, -80, 120, 120, fill='orange' , width=0)
c.pack()

color_cycle = cycle(['light blue', 'light green' , 'light pink' , 'light yellow' , 'light cyan' ])
#assigning important variables
egg_width = 45 
egg_height = 55
egg_score = 10
egg_speed = 200
egg_interval = 3000
difficulty_factor = 0.95

catcher_color ='blue'
catcher_width = 100
catcher_height = 100
catcher_start_x = canvas_width / 2 - catcher_width / 2
catcher_start_y = canvas_height - catcher_height - 20
catcher_start_x2 = catcher_start_x + catcher_width 
catcher_start_y2 = catcher_start_y + catcher_height
#creating the arc for the catcher to catch the eggs
catcher = c.create_arc(catcher_start_x, catcher_start_y, \
                        catcher_start_x2, catcher_start_y2, start=200, extent=140, \
                        style='arc', outline=catcher_color, width=3)
#Writing the score and how much lives you have
game_font = font.nametofont('TkFixedFont')                      
game_font.config(size = 18)
score = 0
score_text = c.create_text(10, 10, anchor = 'nw', font = game_font, fill = 'DarkBlue', \
                           text = 'score: ' + str(score))

lives_remaining = 3
lives_text = c.create_text(canvas_width - 10, 10, anchor='ne', font=game_font, fill = ('darkblue'), \
                           text='Lives:  ' + str(lives_remaining))  
eggs = []
#creating the egg
def create_egg():
    x = randrange(10, 740)
    y = 40
    new_egg = c.create_oval(x, y, x + egg_width, y + egg_height, fill=next(color_cycle) , width=0)
    eggs.append(new_egg)
    root.after(egg_interval, create_egg)
#moving the eggs
def move_eggs():
    for egg in eggs:
        (egg_x, egg_y, egg_x2, egg_y2) = c.coords(egg) 
        c.move(egg, 0, 10)
        if egg_y2 > canvas_height:
            egg_dropped(egg)
    root.after(egg_speed, move_eggs)
#if the eggs reach the bottom of the window, minus one life and delete the egg
def egg_dropped(egg):
    eggs.remove(egg)
    c.delete(egg)
    lose_a_life()
    #if you have 0 lives, write Game Over!
    if lives_remaining == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo('Game Over!', 'Final score: ' \
                            + str(score))
        root.destroy()
  #lose a life
def lose_a_life():
    global lives_remaining
    lives_remaining -= 1
    c.itemconfigure(lives_text, text = 'lives: ' + str(lives_remaining))
#If the catcher(the arc) catches an egg, add 10 to the score and delete it
def check_catch():
    (catcher_x, catcher_y, catcher_x2, catcher_y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    for egg in eggs:
        (egg_x, egg_y, egg_x2, egg_y2) = c.coords(egg)
        if catcher_x < egg_x and egg_x2 < catcher_x2 and catcher_y2 - egg_y2 < 40:
            eggs.remove(egg)
            c.delete(egg)
            increase_score(egg_score)
    root.after(99, check_catch)
#increase the score
def increase_score(points):
    global score, egg_speed, egg_interval
    score += points
    egg_speed = int(egg_speed * difficulty_factor)
    egg_interval = int(egg_interval * difficulty_factor)
    c.itemconfigure(score_text, text='Score: ' + str(score))
#move left
def move_left(event):
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    if x1 > 0:
        c.move(catcher, -20, 0)
#move right    
def move_right(event):
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    if x2 < canvas_width:
        c.move(catcher, 20, 0)
#If the left or right arrow key is hit, move that direction     
c.bind('<Left>', move_left)
c.bind('<Right>', move_right)
c.focus_set()
#Call the game functions
root.after(1000, create_egg)
root.after(1000, move_eggs)
root.after(1000, check_catch)
#Call the main Tkinter loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you want to use an image to replace your egg or your catcher?

Comment: no the background

Comment: hello @jizhihaoSAMA ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image # PIL will import pillow

root = Tk()

my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("C:\\path\\picture.jpg"))
my_label = Label(image=my_img)
my_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please give picture of the image you used

Comment: just took that from my notes, there is no image I used. I used a youtube video on tkinter, took some exampes out of it and changed it to my needs.

Comment: well it said it couldn't open the image

Comment: please help me!

Comment: someone give answer plz

Comment: pleassssssesssss